# I can not see the profile or role when i am going to create new user

Tags: salesforce1-app, force.com

When I am going to create a new user, it does not show me the role or the profile that i want. But it shows in existing users. Does any body know why does do that, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the user, you need to make sure you have selected the correct **User License** that the profile is in. If you do not see the **User License** then that means that you do not have any available licenses of that type

[image]

Comment: Hey I check that. The existing  user and and creating user in same license. But when I am going to create new user with same license, it does not show me.

Comment: AFAIK the User License is the only thing that drives the available Profile

Answer (score 1):

as per the above wanted to add some more information , when you select user license , Profile list will change and display dynamically ...check which use license you selected [image]

-- >In Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, and Developer Editions, we can select a Role.
Select a User License. The user license determines which profiles are available for the user.